# How did the organisers of the Triwizard Tournament arrange a fourth dragon?

Tags: harry-potter

The Triwizard Tournament is always held with 3 participants. It apparently takes months to organise. I assume arranging the dragons must have taken a lot of work, what with training them to treat the golden eggs as their own, and potentially making their attacks non-fatal. It's hard to believe the organisers trained a spare dragon.

So if Harry's participation came as a surprise to everyone, how was it possible to get a fourth dragon so quickly?

Is this explained somewhere in the books or on Pottermore? Or is the time between the selection of champions and the actual task considered sufficient to arrange for an extra dragon?

Comment: The dragon attacks would most likely not have been made non-fatal. It was clearly stated during the introduction of the TWT that injury and death is part of the risk.

Comment: @Nzall - Because that's what you want in a baffling competition between children, a serious chance of them dying.

Comment: @Nzall - "We have worked hard over the summer to ensure that, this time, no champion will find himself or herself in mortal danger." - Dumbledore, Chapter 12, The Triwizard Tournament, Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire.

Comment: @Valorum Technically, considering the age barrier around the goblet, none of them were intended to be children.

Comment: @RajeshJAdvani I suspect Dumbledore managed that with a touch of magic, not with a touch of training.

Comment: @Valorum, it's safer than drinking butterbeer in the village near Hogwarts, because you don't even need any parent permit to fight dragons.

Comment: @Mast - probably true, but either way it seems that even Dumbledore thought it was hard work. One of the ways of preventing fatalities was that a bunch of wizards standing around ready to stun the dragon.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince we learn that they imported **three** dragons, presumably one for each expected competitor.

> *‘Oh, and I almost forgot,’ Fudge had added. ‘**We’re importing three foreign dragons and a sphinx for the Triwizard Tournament**, quite routine, but the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures tells me that it’s down in the rulebook that we have to notify you if we’re bringing highly dangerous creatures into the country.’
>
> ‘I – what – dragons?’ spluttered the Prime Minister.
>
> ‘Yes, three,’ said Fudge. ‘And a sphinx. Well, good day to you.’*

It seems likely that an additional dragon was procured from the nearby **Welsh** Dragon Sanctuary when they realised they'd need an extra one. Note that of the three, the Common Welsh Green is far and away the least aggressive and almost wholly unsuitable for this sort of task. The kind of dragon you'd only use if you had no other choice.

> *This breed* [the Common Welsh Green] *is among the least troublesome of the dragons, preferring,
> like the Opaleye, to prey on sheep and actively avoiding humans unless
> provoked.*
>
> <sub><sup>Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them</sup></sub>

Comment: This is a great answer, and is indeed how I explained it to myself when I first read it!